# Devices to measure RSSI and/or AGC

Tags: rf, signal-processing, telecommunications

I need a way to measure the strength/power of a signal coming from an antenna, 2.4 or 5.8 GHz frequency. Is there any off-the-shelf device that can measure such property? Ideally I would want the value of the RSSI or AGC of the signal, but seeing that these values seem not to be standardized anything that can give me a measure of the strength of the signal is ok for me.

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by the "AGC of the signal". Related to this question: [difference-between-rssi-and-agc-of-a-received-signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/647030/difference-between-rssi-and-agc-of-a-received-signal)

Comment: In most of the papers I read about antenna auto-tracking, they refer to AGC as a measure of the power of the signal in input. I'm not sure why this value is used more often than RSSI but this is not really important in my case as I just need to measure power, I don't care about the format/standard.

Comment: There are ICs that measure RSSI.